# How to assign a unique Id to the dataset row based on some column value in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to assign a unique Id to the row of the dataset based on some column value.
For eg consider that we have a dataset as follows:

```
State Country Person
MH    IN      ABC
AP    IN      XYZ
J&K   IN      XYZ
MH    IN      PQR
```

Now i want to assign a unique Id based on the State Column Value,if the column value repeats furhter the same Id should be populated.
Output should be as follows:

```
State Country Person Unique_ID
MH    IN      ABC     1
AP    IN      XYZ     2 
J&K   IN      XYZ     3
MH    IN      PQR     1
```

How to solve this problem using Spark Java Programming.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using Java? The tags seems to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it with Java Spark.

```
package com.stackoverflow.works;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec; 
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.dense_rank;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.desc;


public class UniqueIdJob {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class Record implements Serializable {

        private String state;

        private String country;

        private String person;

        public Record(String state, String country, String person) {
            super();
            this.state = state;
            this.country = country;
            this.person = person;
        }

        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public String getPerson() {
            return person;
        }

        public void setPerson(String person) {
            this.person = person;
        }

    }

    private static Dataset<Record> createDataset(SparkSession spark) {
        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
        records.add(new Record("MH", "IN", "ABC"));
        records.add(new Record("AP", "IN", "XYZ"));
        records.add(new Record("J&K", "IN", "XYZ"));
        records.add(new Record("MH", "IN", "PQR"));
        records.add(new Record("AP", "IN", "XYZ1"));
        records.add(new Record("AP", "IN", "XYZ2"));
        Encoder<Record> recordEncoder = Encoders.bean(Record.class);
        Dataset<Record> recordDataset = spark.createDataset(records,
                recordEncoder);

        return recordDataset;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("UniqueIdJob")
                .master("local[2]").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Record> recordDataset = createDataset(spark);
        WindowSpec windowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy(desc("state"));
        Dataset<Row> rowDataset = recordDataset.withColumn("id", dense_rank().over(windowSpec));
        rowDataset.show();
        spark.stop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is bit slower however you can do something like follows:

```
select state,country,person,dense_rank() over(order by state) from ds;
```

This should do the job. However, windowing function without partitioning can be slower

Answer (score -1):

You can define your own [UDF](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html)  (User Defined Function). Then you can write your own logic to create the unique id.

Here in the below example, I have created UDF to get unique id with the help of hashcode.

```
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_172)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val dataDF=Seq(("MH",  "IN","ABC"),("AP",  "IN","XYZ"),("J&K","IN","XYZ"),("MH",  "IN","PQR")).toDF("State","Country","Person")
dataDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [State: string, Country: string ... 1 more field]

scala> dataDF.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

scala> def uniqueId(col:String)={col.hashCode}
uniqueId: (col: String)Int

scala> spark.udf.register("uniqueid",uniqueId _)
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,IntegerType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> spark.sql("select state,country,person ,uniqueid(state) as unique_id from table1").show
+-----+-------+------+---------+
|state|country|person|unique_id|
+-----+-------+------+---------+
|   MH|     IN|   ABC|     2459|
|   AP|     IN|   XYZ|     2095|
|  J&K|     IN|   XYZ|    72367|
|   MH|     IN|   PQR|     2459|
+-----+-------+------+---------+
```